# Gracefully loading YAML config with default methods

Tags: python, configuration, yaml, pyyaml

I'm trying to find an elegant way to load values stored in a YAML files into my `__init__` functions for multiple classes. If I have a YAML file containing something like:

```
#YAML
an_object:
  var_a: 1
  var_b: 2
```

With the following module:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, var_a=10, var_b=20, var_c=30):
        self.var_a = var_a
        self.var_b = var_b
        self.var_c = var_c
```

I'd like to use values from the YAML file if they exist, otherwise use the `__init__` method defaults if they don't. I also want it to scale to many variables (>10), so I don't want to try/except each parameter.

My first instinct is to do something like:

```
import yaml 

class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, var_a=10, var_b=20, var_c=30):
        self.var_a = var_a
        self.var_b = var_b
        self.var_c = var_c

        with open('config.yaml','r') as stream:
            cfg = yaml.load(stream)['an_object']

            for key, value in cfg.iteritems():
                if hasattr(self, key):
                    exec("self.{} = {}".format(key, value))
```

But I'd rather not have to use `exec`, nor would I want to assign variables twice (it's a bit confusing). Is there a better way to do this? It would also overwrite the non-default function values, which I wouldn't want to do either.

Comment: You don't need to use `exec`, you could use `setattr(self, key, value)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting the YAML in the `__init__`, I realized it was better to use the config whenever creating an object:

```
import yaml 

class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, var_a=10, var_b=20, var_c=30):
        self.var_a = var_a
        self.var_b = var_b
        self.var_c = var_c

if __name__ == 'main':
    with open('config.yaml','r') as stream:
        cfg = yaml.load(stream)
    sc = SomeClass(**cfg)
```

This keeps the default values, and the only major conflict is assigning multiple keywords, but that's an easy workaround.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`setattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
import yaml 

class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, var_a=10, var_b=20, var_c=30):
        self.var_a = var_a
        self.var_b = var_b
        self.var_c = var_c

        with open('config.yaml','r') as stream:
            cfg = yaml.load(stream)['an_object']

            for key, value in cfg.iteritems():
                if hasattr(self, key):
                    setattr(self, key, value)
```

Please realise that this sets the value to the type whatever YAML determined the value to be in the file. So you have to take care this matches what you expect in the object, or do an explicit conversion.

Also note that this is horribly inefficient as for each instance of this class the YAML file is opened and read. If you create many objects and for different classes, you should make all of these classes subclasses of one `Loader` class that is a singleton, or has the values read from yaml in a class variable, and reads in the values once, then you can do this update in each instantiated object from the values from there (instead of from the file).

To prevent assignment of the default values if the value exists in YAML you must first test if these values exists and then take the default value if they don't:

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml

class Loader(object):
    _val = None

    @property
    def yaml_values(self):
        if Loader._val is None:
            with open('config.yaml','r') as stream:
                Loader._val = yaml.load(stream)
        return Loader._val

    def get_val(self, object_id, key, default):
        try:
            return self.yaml_values[object_id][key]
        except KeyError:
            return default


class SomeClass(Loader):
    obj_id = 'an_object'

    def __init__(self, var_a=10, var_b=20, var_c=30):
        for key in ['var_a', 'var_b', 'var_c']:
            setattr(self, key,
                    self.get_val(SomeClass.obj_id, key, locals()[key]))

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'SomeClass(var_a={}, var_b={}, var_c={})'.format(
            self.var_a, self.var_b, self.var_c)


sc = SomeClass()
print sc
```

will print:

```
SomeClass(var_a=1, var_b=2, var_c=30)
```

Comment: Starting from pyyaml>=5.4 here comes another issue: `TypeError: load() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Loader'`. With [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69581453/19224581) you might investigate it.

Comment: @DariaT I don't think that is appropriate, pyyaml still only supports a subset of the YAML 1.1, outdated in 2009.