# TypeError: load() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Loader' in Google Colab

Tags: python, plotly, typeerror, google-colaboratory, pyyaml

I am trying to do a regular import in Google Colab.
This import worked up until now.
If I try:

```
import plotly.express as px
```

or

```
import pingouin as pg
```

I get an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-86e89bd44552> in <module>()
----> 1 import plotly.express as px

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/plotly/express/__init__.py in <module>()
     13     )
     14 
---> 15 from ._imshow import imshow
     16 from ._chart_types import (  # noqa: F401
     17     scatter,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/plotly/express/_imshow.py in <module>()
      9 
     10 try:
---> 11     import xarray
     12 
     13     xarray_imported = True

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/xarray/__init__.py in <module>()
      1 import pkg_resources
      2 
----> 3 from . import testing, tutorial, ufuncs
      4 from .backends.api import (
      5     load_dataarray,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/xarray/tutorial.py in <module>()
     11 import numpy as np
     12 
---> 13 from .backends.api import open_dataset as _open_dataset
     14 from .backends.rasterio_ import open_rasterio as _open_rasterio
     15 from .core.dataarray import DataArray

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/xarray/backends/__init__.py in <module>()
      4 formats. They should not be used directly, but rather through Dataset objects.
      5 
----> 6 from .cfgrib_ import CfGribDataStore
      7 from .common import AbstractDataStore, BackendArray, BackendEntrypoint
      8 from .file_manager import CachingFileManager, DummyFileManager, FileManager

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/xarray/backends/cfgrib_.py in <module>()
     14     _normalize_path,
     15 )
---> 16 from .locks import SerializableLock, ensure_lock
     17 from .store import StoreBackendEntrypoint
     18 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/xarray/backends/locks.py in <module>()
     11 
     12 try:
---> 13     from dask.distributed import Lock as DistributedLock
     14 except ImportError:
     15     DistributedLock = None

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/dask/distributed.py in <module>()
      1 # flake8: noqa
      2 try:
----> 3     from distributed import *
      4 except ImportError:
      5     msg = (

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/distributed/__init__.py in <module>()
      1 from __future__ import print_function, division, absolute_import
      2 
----> 3 from . import config
      4 from dask.config import config
      5 from .actor import Actor, ActorFuture

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/distributed/config.py in <module>()
     18 
     19 with open(fn) as f:
---> 20     defaults = yaml.load(f)
     21 
     22 dask.config.update_defaults(defaults)

TypeError: load() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Loader'
```

I think it might be a problem with Google Colab or some basic utility package that has been updated, but I can not find a way to solve it.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Found the problem.
I was installing `pandas_profiling`, and this package updated `pyyaml` to version 6.0 which is not compatible with the current way Google Colab imports packages.
So just reverting back to `pyyaml` version 5.4.1 solved the problem.

For more information check versions of `pyyaml` [here](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/#history).
See this issue and formal answers in [GitHub](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/576)

##################################################################
For reverting back to `pyyaml` version 5.4.1 in your code, add the next line at the end of your packages installations:

```
!pip install pyyaml==5.4.1
```

It is important to put it at the end of the installation, some of the installations will change the `pyyaml` version.

Comment: You can also just pin this dependency like you would a normal dependency. The resolver will respect it.

Comment: Thanks! Installing pyyaml==5.4.1 fixed my issue & I was able to import plotly.express without any error in my colab file.

Answer (score 96):

Now, the `load()` function requires parameter `loader=Loader`.

If your YAML file contains just simple YAML (str, int, lists), try to use `yaml.safe_load()` instead of `yaml.load()`.
And If you need **FullLoader**, you can use `yaml.full_load()`.

Starting from pyyaml>=5.4, it doesn't have any discovered critical vulnerabilities, [pyyaml status](https://snyk.io/vuln/pip:pyyaml).

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1774043/13755823

> yaml.safe_load() should always be preferred unless you explicitly need
> the arbitrary object serialization/deserialization provided in order
> to avoid introducing the possibility for arbitrary code execution.

More about `yaml.load(input)` [here](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/wiki/PyYAML-yaml.load(input)-Deprecation).

Answer (score 22):

this worked for me

```
config = yaml.load(ymlfile, Loader=yaml.Loader)
```

Comment: this should be the best answer, particularly when downgrading pyyaml is not an option.

Answer (score 8):

The Python **"TypeError: load() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Loader'"** occurs when we use the `yaml.load()` method without specifying the Loader keyword argument.

To solve the error, use the `yaml.full_load()` method instead or explicitly set the `Loader` keyword arg.

```
 config = yaml.full_load(ymlfile)
```

or

```
config = yaml.load(ymlfile, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install pyyaml==3.12
```

It will work fine for Python 3.10 and you have to update the constructor file also from `collections.Hashable` to `collections.abc.Hashable`.