# TypeError: load() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Loader'

Tags: python, loader, yolo, pyyaml, yolov5

I am trying to run this github repo found at this link: https://github.com/HowieMa/DeepSORT_YOLOv5_Pytorch
After installing the requirements via pip install -r requirements.txt.
I am running this in a python 3.8 virtual environment, on a dji manifold 2g which runs on an Nvidia jetson tx2.

The following is the terminal output.

```
$ python main.py --cam 0 --display
Namespace(agnostic_nms=False, augment=False, cam=0, classes=[0], conf_thres=0.5, config_deepsort='./configs/deep_sort.yaml', device='', display=True, display_height=600, display_width=800, fourcc='mp4v', frame_interval=2, img_size=640, input_path='input_480.mp4', iou_thres=0.5, save_path='output/', save_txt='output/predict/', weights='yolov5/weights/yolov5s.pt')
Initialize DeepSORT & YOLO-V5
Using CPU

Using webcam 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 259, in <module>
    with VideoTracker(args) as vdo_trk:
  File "main.py", line 53, in __init__
    cfg.merge_from_file(args.config_deepsort)
  File "/home/dji/Desktop/targetTrackers/howieMa/DeepSORT_YOLOv5_Pytorch/utils_ds/parser.py", line 23, in merge_from_file
    self.update(yaml.load(fo.read()))
TypeError: load() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Loader'
```

I have found some suggestions on github, such as in here [TypeError: load() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Loader' in Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69564817/typeerror-load-missing-1-required-positional-argument-loader-in-google-col),
which suggests to change yaml.load to yaml.safe_load

This is the code block to modify:

```
class YamlParser(edict):
    """
    This is yaml parser based on EasyDict.
    """
    def __init__(self, cfg_dict=None, config_file=None):
        if cfg_dict is None:
            cfg_dict = {}

        if config_file is not None:
            assert(os.path.isfile(config_file))
            with open(config_file, 'r') as fo:
                cfg_dict.update(yaml.load(fo.read()))

        super(YamlParser, self).__init__(cfg_dict)

    
    def merge_from_file(self, config_file):
        with open(config_file, 'r') as fo:
            self.update(yaml.load(fo.read()))

    
    def merge_from_dict(self, config_dict):
        self.update(config_dict)
```

However, changing yaml.load into yaml.safe_load leads me to this error instead

```
$ python main.py --cam 0 --display
Namespace(agnostic_nms=False, augment=False, cam=0, classes=[0], conf_thres=0.5, config_deepsort='./configs/deep_sort.yaml', device='', display=True, display_height=600, display_width=800, fourcc='mp4v', frame_interval=2, img_size=640, input_path='input_480.mp4', iou_thres=0.5, save_path='output/', save_txt='output/predict/', weights='yolov5/weights/yolov5s.pt')
Initialize DeepSORT & YOLO-V5
Using CPU

Using webcam 0
Done..
Camera ...
Done. Create output file  output/results.mp4
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

Has anyone encountered anything similar ? Thank you !

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```py
yaml.load(fo.read(), Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
```

It seems that pyyaml>=5.1 requires a `Loader` argument.

Comment: Hey @zeit. Thank you. That helped me. I almost got it wrong when i typed Fullloader instead of FullLoader (with the capitalised L).

Answer (score 3):

If you need `FullLoader`, you can also use "sugar" method, `yaml.full_load()`.

And starting from pyyaml>=5.4, it doesn't have any discovered critical vulnerabilities, [pyyaml status](https://snyk.io/vuln/pip:pyyaml).

More about `yaml.load(input)` [here](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/wiki/PyYAML-yaml.load(input)-Deprecation).