# import error while importing vectorbt into Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, importerror

I'm trying to import `vectorbt` into a Google Colab notebook using:

```
!pip install vectorbt

import vectorbt as vbt
```

But I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/distributed/config.py in <module>()
     18 
     19 with open(fn) as f:
---> 20     defaults = yaml.load(f)
     21 
     22 dask.config.update_defaults(defaults)

TypeError: load() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Loader'
```

I searched for possible solution, and I came across [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69564817/typeerror-load-missing-1-required-positional-argument-loader-in-google-col), however, I cannot use earlier version of `pyymal` because one of the other libraries I use need version 6 of `pyymal`.
Is there another way to solve this issue and import `vectorbt` into the Google Colab environment?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
!pip install -U vectorbt

import vectorbt as vbt
```

Comment: I tried, but I still get the same error unfortunately

Comment: I tired it into my colab using python 3.7.13, and it worked. Try to use a different google account.